# Poisson random variable and standard deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, poisson-distribution

I am reading [Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0538733527).

Exercise 81, Chapter 3 says:

> Suppose that the number of drivers who travel between a
>   particular origin and destination during a designated time
>   period has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\mu=20$
>   (suggested in the article “Dynamic Ride Sharing: Theory
>   and Practice,” J. of Transp. Engr., 1997: 308–312). What is
>   the probability that the number of drivers will
>
> - Be within 2 standard deviations of the mean value?

I know that the standard deviation for a Poisson random variable has the same value of the mean (which in this case is $\mu=20$).

Therefore I computed the cumulative density function of the Poisson random variable from $0$ to $60.5$ (2 Standard deviations should be $40$).

However I get as result $0.99999999999986222$ while the correct result seems to be $0.945$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard deviation is the square root of variance.
The variance is $\mu$, and the standard deviation should be $\sqrt{\mu}$.

Answer (score 1):

The mean value and variance  of a Poisson are the same. The  standard deviation is $\sqrt\mu$.  Therefore,

$$P(\mid X-\mu\mid\leq 2\sqrt \mu)=P(\mu-2\sqrt\mu\leq X\leq \mu+2\sqrt \mu)=P(11.05\leq X\leq 28.94)=0.9447$$

approximately.